# Regarding Java Map and Array

Tags: java, javascript, arrays

In Javascript, We can write statement as below.

```
var f_names = {
                'a' : 'Apple',                      
                'b' : 'Banana'
                'c' : 'Carrot'
              };
```

I can call this as `f_names['c']` and get output as `Carrot`.

Is there any equivalent to this in Java instead of Map ? Similar to above ?

We can create an String array as bellow in java.

```
String[] names= { "Apple","Banana", "Carrot" };
```

Then can call as `names[2]` and this will return output as `Carrot`.

I'm looking for solution like this.

Comment: Use HashMap to perform this. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: This is not a conditional statement. It's a JavaScript object, being used as a map. If you don't want to use Java's Map object, please tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Is there any chance you're actually looking for a `switch`?

Comment: @khelwood Yes. It can rewrite with switch but take more no. lines of code. Map will do better :)

Comment: If you want an associative array with `[]` notation, then no. Java does not support that.

Answer (score 3):

That is not at all conditional statement. It's Javascript object. In Java also there is Map.

Yes, you are just looking for [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) in Java. Which stores key value pairs.

```
Map<String, String> map= new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("a", "Apple");
map.put("b", "Banana");
```

And you can retrieve like

```
String a = map.get("a");// which results "Apple"
```

**Update: If you are looking for other ways**

- Take a method which returns String. Add switch case inside method and
  return the result value.
- Take an array of array ex (`{{k,v},{},{}}`). Iterate to get the
  required value.

**Update after your latest comment :**
(*Both JS and Java are languages. if JS can achieve it as above(in simple way), why we use Map for that in Java.*)

You are comparing two languages syntax, it's highly impossible to work with same syntax. If you still want to find the same way, the below would be the closest

```
HashMap<String, String > map = new HashMap<String, String>(){{
        put("a", "Apple");
        put("b", "Banana");
    }};
```

Not sure about your acceptance of this cheat ;)

Comment: That is not at all Javascript map. It's Javascript object.

Comment: @Cerbrus Point taken. Edited.

Comment: The question is *"Is there any equivalent to this in Java **instead if** Map ?"* (I assume they meant "instead *of*").

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, `instead of`. Corrected that :)

Comment: @Bishan yes. There are multiple ways. For example *switch* .. Map will be the easiest way AFAIK. May I know why you are avoiding MAP ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I'm not trying to avoid Map. But trying to find new ways to implement and accessing data :) Both JS and Java are languages. if JS can achieve it as above(in simple way), why we use Map for that in Java. That's why i ask this.

Comment: @Bishan Well, edited a bit. Both are completely different languages. In java script every variable is `var`, which is not possible with Java. Anyways have an edit. Consider changing your title. It's completely misleading.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hmm.. I missed that point initially. Now edited.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax is a bit more complex in Java.

To get the closest equivalent, you can use a `TreeMap`, which will order its keys (default in this case is lexicographic order):

```
Map<String, String> names = new TreeMap<String, String>();
names.put("a", "Apple");
names.put("b", "Banana");
names.put("c", "Carrot");
System.out.println(names);
```

**Output**

```
{a=Apple, b=Banana, c=Carrot}
```

If you **really** don't want to use a `Map`, you can use a double-dimensional `array`.

For instance:

```
String[][] namesArray = new String[][]{{"a","Apple"},{"b","Banana"},{"c","Carrot"}};
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(namesArray));
```

**Output**

```
[[a, Apple], [b, Banana], [c, Carrot]]
```

**Notes**

- Amongst the many advantages of using a `Map` is the fact that you can retrieve your values by key, which is probably something of interest given your context. For instance: `names.get("A")` will return `"Apple`.
- With the `array`, you will need to retrieve your values by indices. For instance, `namesArray[1][1]` is `"Banana"`.

Answer (score 0):

Though Map is the thing you would really want, you could also use enums (I can't really help with those; I lack routine) and public static variables:

```
public final static String a = "Apple";
public final static String b = "Banana";
public final static String c = "Carrot";
```

Then they would be referencable from anywhere in the program. Say if the variables resided in a class named Fruits, they would be referenced to like this:

```
Fruits.a
Fruits.b
Fruits.c
```

Answer (score 0):

This a Javascript Object(Java Script Object Notation) and it is more or less like a key-value pair. In Java this can be achieved by Map interface and the heavily used implementation of this interface is HashMap.